# Add a column in pandas dataframe using conditions on 3 existing columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have an existing Pandas Data-frame that I want to manipulate according to the following pattern:

The existing table has different set of codes in column 'code'. Each 'code' has certain labels listed in column 'label'. Each label has been tagged with either 0 or 1.

I have a requirement to add a 'new_column' with values 0 or 1 for each set of 'code', depending on the following condition:

Fill 1 in the 'new_column' only when all the 'label' of a particular 'code'
has value equals to 1 in the 'tag' column. Note I need to fill 1 for all the rows belonging to that particular 'code'.

As Shown in the desired Table, only code=30 has all the 'label' set in the 'tag' column equals to 1. Therefore i set the 'new_column' equals to 1 for that particular code. Rest of the codes have set to 0 value.

### Existing Table:

```
   code  label  tag
0   10    AAA    0
1   10    BBB    1
2   10    CCC    0
3   10    DDD    0
4   10    EEE    0
5   20    AAA    1
6   20    CCC    0
7   20    DDD    1
8   30    BBB    1
9   30    CCC    1
10  30    EEE    1
```

### Desired Table

```
   code  label  tag  new_column
0   10    AAA    0       0
1   10    BBB    1       0
2   10    CCC    0       0
3   10    DDD    0       0
4   10    EEE    0       0
5   20    AAA    1       0
6   20    CCC    0       0
7   20    DDD    1       0
8   30    BBB    1       1
9   30    CCC    1       1
10  30    EEE    1       1
```

I have not tried any solution yet as it seems beyond my present level of expertise.

Comment: `df.groupby('code')['tag'].transform(all).astype(int)`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but I could not see addition of the 'new_column'  in your code

Comment: Because you need to reassign to the dataframe.  `df[new_column] = ...`..

Comment: I am getting all 0s in the new_column, that is not as per my requirement

Comment: @M.Mufti, I can verify that user3483203 code is working on your given test data and I believe it to be the correct code based on the logic mentioned in the this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right answer for this question is that given by @user3483203 in the comments:

```py
df['new_column'] = df.groupby('code')['tag'].transform(all).astype(int)
```

The [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) method applies to the dataframe whatever is passed to it, keeping the axis length the same.

The simple example in the documentation clearly explains the usage.

Coming to this particular question, the following happens when you run this snippet:

- You first perform the grouping with respect to the 'code'. You end up with a `DataFrameGroupBy` object.
- Next, from this you choose the `tag` column, ending up with a `SeriesGroupBy` object.
- To this grouping, you apply the `all` function via `transform`, ultimately typecasting the boolean values to type `int`.
- Basically, you can understand it like this (the values are binary to make them more related to your answer):

```py
>>> int(all([1, 1, 1, 1]))
1
>>> int(all([1, 0, 1, 1]))
0
```

Finally, you are assigning the column you just created to the column `new_column` to the old dataframe.

Comment: Hi, I have no reason to disagree about the solution but i am still strugling to get the desired result. The new_column shows all zero . Can someone advise.

Comment: Found the reason for not getting the desired result, but it adds another question to my original query . There is another column named 'category'

Comment: There is another column named 'category' that have 3 values say 1, 2 and 3 . The  'tag'  for a 'code' in 'category' 1 is not necessarily same , due to that transform(all) for 'code' 30 is returning False.

Comment: I think its better to post  new query for the changed scenerio, however i am closing the current query by accepting the answer.

Comment: I don't think I completely get the new scenario. As you suggested yourself, you could open a new question (provided it does n't already exist). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the initial answer by user3483203 works. here is a variation. but his way was more concise.

[image]